# Doctrine: Count left joined with condition rows

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine

I created symfony 5 project, which contains user entity with reports (OneToMany relation). I created table with users data using knp paginator. Now I wanna add possibility to order users data by number of last month reports (before I used criteria to get this number, but users data couldn't be ordered by this number). So I added leftJoin reports to users data and count it inside query. Everything works fine, but when I added limitation joined reports to last month('r.createdAt BETWEEN :now AND :lastMonth) result is always '0' to all users.

Code of getting data of users by user repository:

```
    public function findAllQuery(string $searchTerms): Query
    {   

        if ($searchTerms) {
            return $this->searchByTermsQuery($searchTerms);
        }

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            /* This join counts reports correctly but it counts all reports by user (without date limitation)
            ->leftJoin('u.reports', 'r')
            */
            ->leftJoin('u.reports', 'r', Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.createdAt BETWEEN :now AND :lastMonth')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(r.id) AS monthReports')
            ->setParameters([
                'now' => new \DateTime('now'),
                'lastMonth' => new \Datetime('last month')
            ])
            ->groupBy('u.id')
            ->getQuery()
        ;
    }
```

And pagination code:

```
    <th {% if pagination.isSorted('monthReports') %} class="sorted" {% endif %}>
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Month reports', 'monthReports') }}
    </th>
//....
    <td>
        {{ user.monthReports }}
    </td>
```

Can You tell me what I did wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to reverse the order of :now and :lastMonth

```
 ->leftJoin('u.reports', 'r', Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.createdAt BETWEEN :lastMonth AND :now')
```